# How to debug different VS project in solution

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debugging, remote-debugging, visual-studio-debugging

I have a VS Linux Solution set up containing multiple projects.

A main project **A** depends on multiple projects [**B, C, ..., K**].

When debugging **A** remotely, I want my application to stop at a breakpoint somewhere in project **C**'s code.

For now, when I set a breakpoint somewhere in **C**'s code, I keep getting an inacessible-warning:

*"Module containing this breakpoint has not yet loaded or the breakpoint address could not be obtained."*.

I'm aware that I'm debugging a different project than the one I've set VS to debug remotely, however what do I have to setup to make VS know I want multiple projects to have their debug information loaded and accessible?

Comment: Are they in separate processes? You need to start a debugger for each process https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/debug-multiple-processes?view=vs-2019

Comment: @AlanBirtles the dependant project [B, ..., K] are static libs.

Comment: presumably debug symbols are not enabled in the static libraries then or are being stripped before loading into the main project. Please provide a [mre]

Comment: How do I provide a minimal reproducible example for a VS solution?

Comment: Thing is, when stepping into one of the library functions through the main project, I can get into and debug through the files. However, when setting breakpoints, they will never be accessed.

Comment: Is it possible to debug locally(just as a test) to narrow down this issue and see whether this issue is caused by remote debugging or normal VS debugging?

Comment: @Tianyu not really, but I could setup a local test environment just to give it a try. However I normally don't really have time for setting up an extra env.

Comment: @taiBsu, ok, no problem, the error message looks more related to the debug related symbols or files not found. Could you please check if the related generated `.pdb`, `.lib` files are located under the same **solution** folder? For me, I set the `Deployment Directory` for the main project so the related files for debugging are generated into the same folder.